# UIPicker noob question - If I click on first item in the picker, the result is null - all other items are fine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker with 7 items in it.  (only one component)...   If I click on the first item in the Picker (without ANY SCROLLING of the picker), the text results I get back are null.

However, If I so much as "tug" downward on the list and THEN CLICK item #1 it works fine.

If I click ANY other item, it always returns the right result.  Of course, the list has to scroll in order for those items to get selected.

What is happening to cause this?  Is there a delegate function I need to call?  Is there some way to default the selection to the first item in the list, if they never click anything?

Thanks,

Phil

Here is a snippet from "viewdidload" in my .m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        listOfTerms=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                     @"Fall Semester",@"Spring Semester",@"Summer Session",@"Q1",@"Q2",@"Q3",@"Q4",nil];
...
...
```

Here are the other 4 UIPickerView delegate functions I have defined.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}




- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [listOfTerms count];

}





-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [listOfTerms objectAtIndex:row];
}





- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    selectedTerm =[[NSString alloc] 
                       initWithFormat:@"%@",
                       [listOfTerms objectAtIndex:row]];

}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Objective C

Comment: pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: is only called when the picker view scrolls. So if you never scroll the view, the method never gets called and therefore selectedTerm is never set. The fix is simple, initialize selectedTerm in viewDidLoad:.                           On First time your picker is not selected . you can set view by default of row at index 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` is only called when the picker view scrolls. So if you never scroll the view, the method never gets called and therefore selectedTerm is never set. The fix is simple, initialize selectedTerm in `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: Thanks, man.  That did the trick.  Seems like clicking on it should invoke some delegate function though.  Seems strange that you have to scroll in order to pick the first item on the list.  (..and have to init the result to the first item on the list in order to accommodate the lameness.)  It's working now though - thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer for all situation is to imply didSelectRow in **viewDidAppear**

(Please note that it is NOT **viewDidLoad** method)

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
    [self pickerView:[self yourpickerview] didSelectRow:0 inComponent:0;
}
```